# C# TreeView Foreground Color Node

Tags: c#, colors, treeview

I can set colors of nodes with the `ForegroundColor` property, but one strange problem occurs:

If you select a colored node (no matter what color), and then left-click any other node, while the mouse is down, the node reverts to its original color (black in my case). As soon as I release the mouse, the foreground color is set again.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is by design. But it stays like that only while the mouse is pressed down, so it shouldn't be much of a distraction to user, in fact, its an indication to user that the control detected your action.
But if you are keen on changing that behavior, override `onMouseDown` event

Comment: where is the "fallback"-color set? is it always black? can i change it somehow? the blinking is annoying me...

Comment: In `OnMouseDown` event, set whatever color you wish to the node you are selecting.